# Google is not finding my product images - Magento 1.7 CE

Tags: magento-1.7, product-images, seo

Google images are not displaying any of our product images; whether we Google for the company name or not, perhaps I'm doing something wrong.

Our web site is [www.bellydeluxe.de](http://www.bellydeluxe.de)

If someone could take a look and give me some insights in to what I can do to ensure our image results show up on Google, that would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

We are using Google rich Snippet for this purpose you can check schema.org Documentation for this

Here is the link for schema.org Look at their documentation

https://schema.org/docs/gs.html